# How to disable TLS 1.0 from JDK

Tags: java, security, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

To disable SSLv3 we have added `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" \`environment variable to Java 8 run time. However due to TLSv1.0 has been considered as a weak protocol, we want to disable it from the Transport Layer Security protocols.

- So just want to know whether TLSv1 is equal to TLSv1.0 ? or
- TLSv1 mean it(client) will pick any Transport Layer Security protocols supported by the server(other than TLSv1.0 )?

Answer (score 3):

`TLSv1` is the java identifier for TLSv1.0, it's not a "wildcard" for all types of TLS. In addition to the system-property you already set, you should set `https.protocols` to the same values because classes in the JVM will check this setting instead of the others. See the [Oracle's CVE-documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html) about this for more details.